# Downloading from a Sharepoint list using webservice

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am writing a program in which I use the list webservice of sharepoint and the webclient.DownloadFile method of C# to download all files in a list. The list contains 1800 files which are displayed in 18 pages, resulting in 100 files in each page. However, my code only downloads the files in the first 10 pages (1000 files out of 1800 files). Anyone have any idea what the problem is?
Here is my code

```
XmlNode ndListItems = null;        
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();         
XmlNode ndQuery = xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "");        
XmlNode ndViewFields = xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "");            
XmlNode ndQueryOptions = xdoc.CreateNode  (XmlNodeType.Element, "QueryOptions", "");         
ndQuery.InnerXml = "";        
ndViewFields.InnerXml = "";        
ndQueryOptions.InnerXml   = "<IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>";    
ndListItems = list.GetListItems(ListName, "", ndQuery, ndViewFields, "1000",   ndQueryOptions, null);   
 if (ndListItems!=null)         
 {             foreach (XmlNode node in ndListItems.ChildNodes)                  {                  if ( node.Name=="rs:data")                
 {                     string[] foldernames = new string[node.ChildNodes.Count];                    
 for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)                          {                         if (node.ChildNodes[i].Name == "z:row" && node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes != null)                        
 {                             string fileurl= node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["ows_ServerUrl"].Value;                            
 string filename = node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["ows_LinkFilename"].Value;                            
 string contenttype = node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["ows_ContentType"].Value;                             
string copysource = serverAddress + fileurl;                          
  Uri copyUrl = new Uri(copysource);                             
if   (contenttype=="Folder")                            
  {                                 foldernames[i] = filename;                                
 Directory.CreateDirectory(copyDestination+ filename);                                     continue;                             }                                try                             {                               
   int index = FolderNamseContain(filename, copysource, foldernames);                          
      if (index != -1)                                       {                         wc.DownloadFile(copysource, copyDestination + foldernames[index] + "\\" + filename);                                    
 report.Write(fileurl);                                    
 report.WriteLine();                                     
report.Flush();                                 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
ndListItems = list.GetListItems(ListName, "", ndQuery, ndViewFields, "1000",   ndQueryOptions, null)
```

You have specified a row limit of 1000 items. Change it to this:

```
ndListItems = list.GetListItems(ListName, "", ndQuery, ndViewFields, "2000",   ndQueryOptions, null)
```

Comment: @user1260960: the best way to thank sga101 is to click the upvote arrow and the accept answer checkmark for this question.